# Object isn't an instance of Koa on the "require" side

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

This is a weird bug so I must be missing something obvious, but here it is.

I'm trying to set up a Koa server to serve several Koa apps depending on the vhost name. The entry point is `server.js` :

```
const _ = require("lodash");
const compose = require("koa-compose");
const Koa = require("koa");
const server = module.exports = new Koa();
const app1 = require("./apps/app1");
const app2 = require("./apps/app2");

console.log(app1 instanceof Koa); // false (!)
console.log(app1); // `{ subdomainOffset: 2, proxy: false, env: 'development' }`

const vhostApps = [
  { vhost: "localhost", app: composer(app1) }, // composer fails because app1 is not a Koa instance
  { vhost: "app1.mydomain.com", app: composer(app1) },
  { vhost: "app2.mydomain.com", app: composer(app2) }
];

server.use(async function(ctx, next) {
  const app = _(vhostApps).find({ vhost: ctx.hostname }).app;
  return await app ? app.apply(this, [ctx, next]) : next();
});

if (!module.parent) server.listen(process.env.PORT || 80);

function composer(app) {
  const middleware = app instanceof Koa ? app.middleware : app;
  return compose(middleware);
}
```

Then, there's `./apps/app1/index.js`, the entry point of one app:

```
const Koa = require("koa");
const serve = require("koa-static");
const views = require("koa-views");
const router = require("./routes");

const app = new Koa();

app.use(serve(__dirname + "/assets"));
app.use(views(__dirname + "/views", { map: { html: "lodash" } }));
app.use(router.routes());

console.log(app instanceof Koa); // true (OK)
console.log(app); // `{ subdomainOffset: 2, proxy: false, env: 'development' }`

module.exports = app;
```

In this module, `app` is an instance of Koa (thus it has a `middleware` property, of type array).

But seen from `server.js`, the value imported from `app1` is **not the expected Koa instance**, even though the logged values of `app` and `app1` are the same (`{ subdomainOffset: 2, proxy: false, env: 'development' }`
).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you try `app1 instanceof Koa` from server.js?

Comment: It says `false`! (I've slightly edited my question and its title to make this clear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I think found what the problem was, and, as it happens, the essential piece of info was missing in my question.

The `./apps/app1` folder has its own `node_modules`, with its own copy of Koa. Therefore, `server.js` and `apps/app1/index.js` each have their own, different, Koa.

So I suppose that in the line: `const middleware = app instanceof Koa ? app.middleware : app;`, `app instanceof Koa` will always return false for that reason.

One solution is simply to remove Koa from the app's node_modules, so Koa is inherited from the outer folder. (At first sight, it has some drawbacks for me because I would like to the apps to be standalone).

But I think I'll just skip the `instanceof Koa` test and have `const middleware = app.middleware;` instead (I borrowed the original line from https://github.com/koajs/examples/blob/master/vhost/app.js#L14).